# Impossible to upgrade Brownie package via pip or pipx command - version still showing 16.4.1 after the upgrade

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pipx

I am trying to upgrade my version of Brownie, currently v.16.4.

I have tries all commands :

- Pip install --upgrade eth-brownie
- Pipx upgrade eth-brownie
- even via commandsetupsand git clone....

I am not having ay issues or errors, each time the upgrade is successful ... however the upgrade tells me i have the ;ast version already, while version 18.x.x is already available since months.....

I am running with a Mac M 2021 version (latest build as of today) and have Python3 version 3.10

Anyone facing the same issue ?

Comment: Can you post the error traceback?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this and described the solution in details here :
https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/cannot-verify-my-erc721uristorage-contract-using-brownie/28295/2
and here : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/115371/brownie-deployment-keyerror-openzeppelin-openzeppelin-contracts4-4-0-addres

Basically brownie can't upgrade or instal v1.18.1 if you are using Python 3.10 or higher. This is due to certain brownie package dependencies that require a python version strictly lower than 3.10. You need to downgrade to python v.3.9.x, update your path and reinstall brownie via pip after.

Hope it will help others.